# c++ different behavior of a float variable in function CallBackFunc (Opencv)

Tags: c++, function, opencv

```
std::string temp="22.7";
float a  = std::stof(temp);
cout<< "a:"<< a <<endl;
```

Hi to everyone, i'm a beginner in c++. I've these lines in an opencv function called `CallBackFunc()`. If O print the var `a` from the `CallBackFunc()`, I obtain "a:22" as output while in the `main()` these 3 lines gives me the expected output "a:22.7".

How is it possible? I don't really understand. I've tried on different IDE so I think that there is something wrong.

I've tried lot of things but...

I expect that even in `CallBackFunc` the output will be "a:22.7"

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"




void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y,  int flags, void* userdata)
{
    /////////////////////////////HERE THE OUTPUTIS "a:22"
    std::string temp="22.7";
    double c_a  = std::stod(temp);
    cout<< "TAKE POINT INFOOO"<< c_a <<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    namedWindow("Webcam", WINDOW_FULLSCREEN); //migliore fin ora: WINDOW_AUTOSIZE
    createTrackbar( "track1", "Webcam", NULL, 1,  NULL);

    ////////////////////////////HERE THE OUTPUTIS "a:22.7"
    std::string temp="22.7";
    double c_a  = std::stod(temp);
    cout<< "TAKE POINT INFOOO"<< c_a <<endl;
   

   
    while(true)
    {
        
        setMouseCallback("Webcam", CallBackFunc, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Do you change locale (and use `,` a decimal separator)?

Comment: Try to use the extra parameter to know the number of processed characters.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you sir. With ```,``` it works in the callbackfunc! But, i have to say, it doesn't work in main! So i have to keep ```.``` in main function and ```,``` in CallBackFunc. It seems so strange

Comment: [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) (C++17) might help.

Comment: @Jarod42 the problem is that i use C++11 and i have a csv of temperature, that have to be expressed with ```.```

Comment: Try to see where you change locale (directly or indirectly).